# not allowed to load local resource index.html

Tags: file, webpack, electron

I have downloaded the electron-webpack-quick-start from github and tried to replace the default code with an index.html file.

```
win.loadURL(url.format({
  pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
  protocol: 'file:',
  slashes: true
}))
```

But im getting this error:

```
Not allowed to load local resource
```

I have tried to disable websecurity and the error disappears but nothing is shown.

i have also tried to add:

```
"files": [
"*.js",
"build",
"node_modules"]
```

to my package.json

Comment: Try to rebuild run again
`yarn dev`.

Comment: I have tried it several times with no luck. I have switched to electron-forge now and it works for me.

Comment: Ok electron-forge seems good!
Have a good luck in your development!